# how to get unique values in django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I have a category model and list of posts related to those category also some post with same category name but when i wanted to make list of category section in template,
it showing duplicate name of category as it related to posts like:

food,
food,
desert,
style,
desert,
but I want like:

food,
desert,
style,
here is my code:

**views.py**

```
class ListCategory(ListView):
    model = Post
    paginate_by = 2
    template_name = 'shit.html'
    context_object_name = 'queryset'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        cate = Post.objects.all()
        context['cate'] = cate
        return context
```

**models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    detail = models.TextField()
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-category', kwargs={
        'pk': self.pk
    })
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    overview = models.TextField()
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(Author,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    thumbnail = models.ImageField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    tags = TaggableManager()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={
         'pk': self.pk
    })
```

**templates**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="sidebar-box ftco-animate">
    <ul class="categories">
        <h3 class="heading mb-4">Categories</h3>
         {% for cat in cate %}
             <li><a href="{% url 'post-category' cat.category.pk %}">{{cat.category}}<span>(12)</span></a></li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Thank you so much!

Comment: So do you want to _group_ your `Post` objects based on their categories?

Comment: I want to make list of unique category section in my template .. as you can see when i use for loop to get all categories but it showing duplicate name because of foreignkey . But i want unique name of category how to have that feature

Comment: Then why aren't you iterating over `Category` to get them? Let me know If you want to display `Post`s based on their category.

Comment: yes bro! how can i do that? and would it be possible to get specific posts based with category by url ? as i getting now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you want to **group** your `Posts`, based on their `category`; so you can achieve that by iterating over the `Category` (instead of `Post`), and use the **backward relationship** to find out the related `Post` objects.

**views.py**

```
class ListCategory(ListView):
    model = Category
    paginate_by = 2
    template_name = 'shit.html'  # :)
    context_object_name = 'queryset'
```

**template**:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block content %}
<div class="sidebar-box ftco-animate">
    <ul class="categories">
        <h3 class="heading mb-4">Categories</h3>
         {% for category in queryset %}
             <li><a href="{% url 'post-category' category.pk %}">{{category}}<span>{{ category.posts_set.count }}</span></a></li>
             <ul>
                 {% for post in category.post_set.all %}
                     <li><a href="{% url 'post-detail' post.pk %}">{{ post }}</a></li>
                 {% endfor %}
             </ul>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

I also use `{{ category.post_set.count }}` instead of `12`, since I think you are looking for the number of `Post` objects within each category.

Comment: thank you so much! so much appreciate bro! its been few days i was stuck with it..all   is working fine just ...but it doesn't show number of category  {{ category.posts_set.count }} can i know why ?

Comment: Glad to help. It should be `{{ category.post_set.count }}`; just an extra `s` :)

Comment: cool bro ! bro if you dont mind, is there any way that i can talk to you the stuck time :)

Comment: You can find contact information (twitter) on my profile.

Comment: bro can you little bit explain about you had no any context for {% for post in category.post_set.all %} but how this thing working also your twitter didn't allow me to knock you seems like disable to text :( ..i have some talk to share with you :|

Comment: The code works because you are using generic `ListView`. Check the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#built-in-class-based-generic-views) for more details. I also fixed disabled texting; sorry about that. You can also contact me in Telegram with the same id.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `unique=True` in desired field, to make every value unique. If you'll try to add new record with same value of `unique` field, a `django.db.IntegrityError` will be raised.

[More about `unique`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#unique)

[More about model's fields options](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/models/#field-options)

Comment: In category model, name of categories was unique but as you can see in post model foreignkey allows a single category can have multiple posts for that reason it's showing duplicate name but i want not to see  same category name multiple times in category section